# Facebook Access App Page

Tags: facebook, api

I'm making a Facebook App for the first time, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I have created my app and plugged in the App On Facebook details, and I now am trying to figure out how to view the app on Facebook to test it. I can't find any button for "Go To App", only edit, and I can't find the app on Facebook itself. How do I view the app to test it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the following URL in the address bar of your browser:

https://apps.facebook.com/[namespace]

[namespace] must be the app namespace that you have created on facebook. To see the namespace of you app, go to developers.facebook.com then click on Apps and after that in the left menu select your app. In the current page you will see the app namespace.